# How to remove log debugging statements from a program

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I am using `boost::log` as a logger for my C++ program.
During development I often use it this way, for example:

```
#define LOG(severity) BOOST_LOG_SEV(boost::logger::get(), (severity))
#define LOG_ERR LOG(Severity::error)
#define LOG_INFO LOG(Severity::info)
#define LOG_DEBUG LOG(Severity::debug)
```

where `BOOST_LOG_SEV` is the facility provided by `boost::log`, while `LOG`, `LOG_ERROR`, `LOG_INFO`, `LOG_DEBUG` are shortcuts defined by me.

In short, `BOOST_LOG_SEV` dynamically compares the current debugging severity with the severity passed to the macro itself to decide whether to emit the output or not.

This is an example of a program which use the above macros for debugging purposes:

```
// set at compile time
#define MAX_LOG_SEVERITY Severity::debug

int main() {
   // Print all the messages with a
   // Severity <= MAX_LOG_SEVERITY defined before compiling
   boost::log::set_severity(boost::logger::get(), MAX_LOG_SEVERITY); // set_severity() is fictitious just to give you an idea

   // bool err = ...
   if (err)
      LOG_ERR << "An error occurred";
   else 
      LOG_INFO << "Okay;
   LOG_DEBUG << "main() called";
}
```

Now, when releasing the program for a production environment, debugging messages with a `Severity::debug` level do not really make sense. I could hide them from the output by simply decreasing `MAX_LOG_SEVERITY` to `Severity::info`, but the problem is that the calls made by `LOG_DEBUG` will not be removed from the executable code. This has a bad impact on both efficiency and object size.

The code is full of logging statements and I'd really like to preserve the simple use of `operator<<()`.

Without touching those statements themselves, is there any better macro definition/trick for `LOG_DEBUG` that would make the pre-processor or the compiler (during its optimizations) "skip" or "remove" the debugging statements when `MAX_LOG_SEVERITY` is set to the `Severity::debug` constant ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I can't make any guarantees, something like this might work. It depends on what your optimizer does and whether or not you have side effects in the parameters to operator<<.

```
#ifdef NO_LOG_DEBUG

static class DevNull
{
} dev_null;

template <typename T>
DevNull & operator<<(DevNull & dest, T)
{
    return dest;
}

#define LOG_DEBUG dev_null

#else

#define LOG_DEBUG LOG(Severity::debug)

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

@MartinShobe's accepted answer works on:

- g++ (4.7.2) with `-O1` and higher
- clang++ (3.4) with `-O2` and higher
- Visual Studio (2008) with linker flag `/OPT:REF`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work for me (MSVC 2019, stdc++17).

My solution is a bit whacky though. But the optimization should definitely take care of it:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define LOG_DEBUG if (false) std::cout
#else
#define LOG_DEBUG if (true) std::cout
#endif
```

Usage:

```
LOG_DEBUG << ... << std::endl;
```

Answer (score -2):

Turns off all optimizations in the program and speeds compilation.

/Od
or boot_log_stop