# Is there a way to remove text literals from release binary when using boost::log API?

Tags: c++, boost

boost 1.55 provides a logging API using the C++ streams insertion operator (otherwise named the left-shift operator).

While the syntax is convenient, I cannot think of a way to discard debug text literals from the executable file.

Using MFC, for instance, the TRACE macro ends up to be an empty line in release configuration.

Using TRACE (or any such kind of macro function):

```
TRACE("This text literal shall only be found in debug configuration");
```

Using Boost API:

```
LOG_DEBUG << "This text literal shall only be found in debug configuration";
```

I tested (using Visual Studio 2010, Compiler Full Optimization (/Ox) enabled) the [How to remove log debugging statements from a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027876/how-to-remove-log-debugging-statements-from-a-program) thread suggestion but the literal ends up in the executable in release (which makes sense, as far as I could predict the outcome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, but it requires rewriting the log statements:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define LOG(arg) LOG_DEBUG << arg
#else
#define LOG(arg)
#endif
```

the line

```
LOG("This text literal shall only be found in debug configuration");
```

will be preprocessed to nothing for a non-debug build. Streaming still works, too:

```
LOG("Answer = " << 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [empty `operator<<` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16028265/1462337) does work for me on Visual Studio 2008. The key seems not to be a *compiler* optimization flag but a *linker* optimization flag. When I link with [`/OPT:REF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976(v=vs.100).aspx) (Eliminate Unreferenced Data) then the string literals are not in the executable.

One thing that is a little confusing is the default:

> If /DEBUG is specified, the default for /OPT is NOREF (otherwise, it
>   is REF), and all functions are preserved in the image.

One might think that means that a Release build would have `/OPT:REF` by default and so specifying the flag is unnecessary. On my Visual Studio, however, it appears that a Release build has `/DEBUG` enabled by default (which may be useful but is somewhat counter-intuitive) so you must add `/OPT:REF` to the Release build flags if you want that behavior.

Comment: I tried using the REF option and using VS2008 with same results. I figured out that the linker had nothing to do with this, in fact: I generated a console project in VS2008 defining the DevNull class before the main (so in same module). In debug, the literal was there, but NOT in release... using REF... or NOREF explicitly! I noticed the compiler optimization was set to "Maximize Speed (/O2)" instead of "Full Optimization (/Ox)" which **IS** what makes the difference. It ends up that the other solution is much simpler and easily portable but this post was also highlighting interesting facts.